# Visual Studio Code multi-line comment for files with no extension

Tags: comments, visual-studio-code

I'm editing a file with no extension (for example... or a file with an unknown extension, etc), and when i try to multi-line comment using Cmd+/ it doesn't do anything.  I can change the extension to .py or .yaml to get the # comment feature i'm looking for, but that's a total pain.  Is there a way to tell code "act like a .py extension on the file" type of thingy?... or maybe replace CarriageReturn+LineFeed with CarriageReturn+LineFeed plus # plus space ...  or FORCE the Cmd+/ to work?

Comment: It could be done with a command but you couldn't `toggle` it off with the same command.

Comment: How do i do a command?  Can i create two, one on, one off?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a couple of solutions that works... NO extensions, etc...

Just hold (mac)Option+Cmd (while in column 1), then click down arrow to multi-cursor select all of the lines, then simply type # to put that in col.1, and remainder will move over 1 column to right... you can do this again, to add another #, for example.

Also, another option is to:
-Go to Selection> ColumnSelectionMode, (put into column mode) then drag down, does "multi-select"!!  ..then type # to comment lines, for example!!

Comment: And then do the same to toggle the comments off - seems like a lot of work each time to avoid using a macro extension ;>}  Instead of Ctrl+/ and Shift+/ from anywhere on the line.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little surprised but this seems to work - test it out.  You will need a macro extension of some sort.  Here I am using the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

In your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

 {
   "command": "multiCommand.addCommentNoExtension",
   "sequence": [

     "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",        
     "cursorHome",
     {
       "command": "type",
       "args": {
         "text": "# "
       }
     },
    "removeSecondaryCursors"
   ]      
 },

{
  "command": "multiCommand.removeCommentNoExtension",
  "sequence": [

    "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",        
    "cursorHome",
    "deleteRight",
    "deleteRight",
    "removeSecondaryCursors"
  ]
 }
]
```

In your keybindings.json put these keybindings:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.addCommentNoExtension" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceFilename =~ /^(?!.*\\.)/" 
},

{
  "key": "shift+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.removeCommentNoExtension" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceFilename =~ /^(?!.*\\.)/" 
},
```

Here is a demo:

[image: demo of commenting a file with no extension].

---

There are some limitations to this approach rather than a full-blown extension.

1. The last cursor position will not be remembered.
2. Empty lines will be commented - as you can see in the demo.
3. When block-commenting lines of different indentation, the comment `#`'s won't line up.
4. You have to use one keybinding <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to add comments, and another binding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to remove comments.  I don't think there is a way to make it a one-command toggle.

---

The really **interesting part** of this answer is how **files with no extension** are targeted.  In the keybindings there are when clauses that include `resourceFilename =~ /^(?!.*\\.)/`.

When clauses can take a regex to apply to certain keys like `resourceFilename`.  See [when clause operators](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyvalue-when-clause-operator). The regex `/^(?!.*\\.)/` says to apply this keybinding when the filename does not include a literal `.`.  It uses a negative lookahead asserting that there is no `.` following any characters.

I wasn't sure that was possible but it seems to work.  The <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> command still works as it should with other file types.

---

You could use `"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == plaintext"` and that would work as long as your files with no extension remained as `plaintext` langId files. It isn't quite as specific as the when clause I used above.